# ScheduledExecutorService waits for task to complete, does pending tasks pile up to ultimately interrupting main thred?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I was curious for my new implementation using ScheduledExecutorService in which the task is expected to finish within 100ms period and 0ms delay. But in case if there is system load and its taking say 550 ms, would there be a queue maintained by ScheduledExecutorService for those pending 4 tasks? And then run as soon as (0ms delay) first one is finished. And what if second execution takes 560 ms , would that add another 4 threads to its queue?

There is not documentation around that, or I might be overlooking it. But I want to make sure that the pile up of such executions would trigger to leak or overflow.

For example: below code, could main thread ever fail?

```
    private static ScheduledExecutorService consumerThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        consumerThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> performTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static void performTask () {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(550);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks will be skipped if they overrun the next scheduled time, you can verify easily with System.out.println and alter the sleep under 500ms to 5000ms:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
    var executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    var count = new AtomicInteger();

    Runnable task = () -> {
        String desc = "run("+((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60)+") "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" count "+count.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(desc);
        if(count.get() == 50)
            throw new RuntimeException("I give up!");

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" INTERRUPTED");
        }
    };
    var future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    System.out.println("Calling future.get() ...");
    try {
        var res = future.get();
        System.out.println("future.get()="+res);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("There was an exception:" +e);
        // Decide between "continue" or "throw e" here
        // ...
    }
    executor.shutdownNow();
    System.out.println("shutdown complete");
}
```

Comment: JDK says next task will execute "subsequently with the given delay
between the termination of one execution and the commencement of
the next"